# How to connect an HID RFID reader to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: rfid, hid

I have seen plenty of tutorials to connect an RC522 module to a Raspberry Pi, but I have been given an HID iClass SE reader to integrate into our system which runs off a Raspberry Pi 3B.  I have no idea which pins on Pi I should connect to.  I have found some tutorials on the code I can use, but first I need to connect it correctly.  The spec sheet attached is for the top end model and shows a dozen connections, but this model has only four wires (Red, Black, White, Green).  Presuming that they would use the same colors for all models, here's what I have from the spec sheet.

|Wire Color |Terminal | Description|

| Red |         P1-4 |+VDC (I believe this is 12V DC) |

| Black |       P1-3 | Ground (RTN) |

| White |       P2-4 | **Wiegand Data 1 / Clock|

| Green |       P2-3 | **Wiegand Data 0 / Data |

So where do I connect the White and Green on the Pi?

As suggested below is a photo and the link to the device is: https://www.hidglobal.com/products/readers/iclass-se/r10
[image: HID iClass SE]

Comment: Perhaps you can show us a link and a photo of your specific HID RFID reader. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HID_Global, 
https://www.hidglobal.com/products/cards-and-credentials/iclass

Comment: `Presuming that they would use the same colors for all models` and `I believe this is 12V DC` ... please do not presume and do not guess ... read the datasheet and be sure ... it could just as easily be a USB connection

Comment: Thanx @jsotola - I presumed because they have a common sheet for all their models (it came in the package).  And the person who gave it to me told me it was 12V - he has used it in the past.  Plus it scans cards and behaves :-) with 12V input on Back and Green

Comment: These two references might get you started: (1) Wiegand Interface - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiegand_interface, 
(2) Wiegand Reader for Raspberry Pi- alperenguman
https://github.com/alperenguman/rpi-wiegand-reader